# Instruction set simulator(SystemC) for MIPS architecture

Tags: mips, qemu, instruction-set, systemc

Does anybody know if there is a open source MIPS instruction set simulator (in C++ or SystemC preferably)?

I googled dozens of links and there is just no open ISS of MIPS cpu. Then only ones I know for now is

- Plasma CPU, which implements only a limited number of mips instructions, thus some application code can not be simulated by it.
- Gem5, which I was not able to use to boot a linux image(though followed every instruction on its web)

So, do you have some experience about this?

Comment: It's a lot of work, so I wouldn't expect anybody doing it for free, unless it's a student project, in which case there are likely to be cut corners and uncertain liabilities. In commercial environment it would probably take a month or more to design, optimize, test, and document it at a cost of $xxxxx.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [QEMU](http://qemu.org/)? I use it in my [ELLCC](http://ellcc.org) project to do both Linux user mode and bare system mode emulation for the Mips.

Answer (score 0):

(1) GXemul
(2) OVPsim from OVPworld. It is free for research purpose.